# Ruby on Rails Controller Instance Variable not shared

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

My 'new' action generates the cart object @cart out of a session. When I call the 'update' action via AJAX the @cart object doesn't exist. Why is it not shared across the controller?

cart_controller.rb

```
def new
  @cart = Cart.new(session[:cart])
end

def update
  logger.debug @cart.present? # false
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`@cart` is an instance variable and it is not persisted between requests. And `session` is accessible between requests.

Basically if you have set some data into session then you can use that data between requests. As it was mentioned you can setup a `before_filter` and preset `@cart` instance variable before executing the `update` action.

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_action :instantiate_cart, only: [:update] #is the list of actions you want to affect with this `before_action` method
  ...
  private

  def instantiate_cart
    @cart = Cart.new(session[:cart])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables (starting with `@`) are not shared between requests (or across controller actions). You can denote a method in order to get cart. Here is an example:

```
def new
  cart
end

def update
  logger.debug cart.present?
end

private

def cart
  @cart ||= Cart.new(session[:cart])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The *instance variables* can't be shared across the controller. They are available to the `actions` where they are defined. So you can't use `@cart` in `update` action since you didn't define it.

```
def new
  @cart = Cart.new(session[:cart])
end

def update
  @cart = Cart.new(session[:cart])
  logger.debug @cart.present?
end
```

To *DRY* the code, use `before_action` to set the cart

```
before_action :set_cart, only: [:new, :update]

def new
end

def update
  logger.debug @cart.present?
end

private
def set_cart
  @cart = Cart.new(session[:cart])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: controller instance variables are not shared across different HTTP requests as each request create a new instance of the controller.

Conceptually what you are expecting should have been correct! You are defining an instance variable and you should have access to it everywhere across the class.

The problem is that on every HTTP request, a new instance of the class is being created.

So when you hit the `new` action an instance of the controller will be initiated, `new` method will be called and `@cart` will be created and assigned. Something like:

```
# HTTP request /new
controller = MyController.new # an object of your controller is created
controller.new # the requested action is called and @cart is assigned
```

But when you make a new HTTP request to `update` a new instance of the controller will be initiated, `update` method will be called and it has no `@cart`!

```
# HTTP request /update
controller1 = MyController.new # an object of your controller is created
controller1.new # the requested action is called and @cart is not assigned
```

As you can see `controller` and `controller1` are two different objects initiated from `MyController` as this took place in two different HTTP requests (different contexts).

To fix your issue you need to create `@cart` for each action when it's needed something like:

```
def new
  cart
end

def update
  logger.debug cart.present?
end

private

def cart
  @cart ||= Cart.new(session[:cart])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `before_action` to create the instance of `@cart`, in the case the `@cart` instance variable will be visible to `new` and `update` actions.

```
before_action :get_cart, only: [:new, :update]

private
def get_cart
  @cart = Cart.new(session[:cart])
end
```

If you don't want to use action callbacks, another alternative is calling `get_cart` method directly to `new` and `update` actions. Since, `get_cart` returns the instance `@cart`. As reference to this you can see this [link](https://medium.com/@shvetsovdm/an-alternative-to-rails-before-action-eb010c3ffbfb)